# UpdateSourceTrigger usage C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, updatesourcetrigger

I am currently using this `AutoCompleteTextBox` in my project: [WPFTextBoxAutoComplete](https://github.com/Nimgoble/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/)

I am binding the TextBox to a `List<string>` of Employee names. I am doing this like so;

```
<TextBox 
    Width="250"  Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    behaviors:AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
/>
```

What I want the `TextBox` to do is offer a suggestion when the user types in an Employee's name. However, no suggestion appears at all, which leads me to believe that I am not binding the `UpdateSourceTrigger` properly.

If I am only binding the behaviour to a `List<string>` then how does the `Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` work when there  is no property of the Employee's name? I am  a little unsure as to what needs to change to trigger the update source.

The website provides this explanation: *Now, every time the "TestText" property of your datacontext is changed, WPFTextBoxAutoComplete will provide you with auto-completion suggestions.*

However, I don't believe my `DataContext` has a "Name" property.

**EDIT**:

```
/**** AutoComplete ****/
public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoCompleteTest = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Test", typeof(string), typeof(CompanyManagement), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string Test
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(AutoCompleteTest); }
    set { SetValue(AutoCompleteTest, value); }
}
```

**TextBox XAML**

```
        <TextBox 
            Width="250"  Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            behaviors:AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
        />
```

Comment: You can debug the binding and see exactly what happens with the text. You can do so by adding the `Text="{Binding Name, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` to the Text and add the `xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"` to the window definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a property called `Name` in your `DataContext` with change notification (either with `DependencyProperty` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

1. With `DependencyProperty`:

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "Name", typeof (string), typeof (WhateverClassYouHave), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

   public string Name
   {
       get { return (string) GetValue(NameProperty); }
       set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
   }
   ```
2. With `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

   ```
   public class WhateverClassYouHave: INotifyPropertyChanged

   private string _name;
   public string Name
   {
       get { return _name; }
       set
       {
           _name = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); // C# 6 feature
       }
   }

   [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); // C# 6 feature
   }
   ```

As you type, the `Name` property will change, notify the behavior about the change and it will offer you the suggestion.

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I change this so that it fills in based on an `List<string>` of employee Names?

Comment: In your `DataContext` just have a property called `Employees`. I assigned it like this: `Employees = new List<string> { "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Lara Croft", "Sam Fisher", "Szabolcs Dézsi" };`

Comment: Thanks again. I am now getting an error however : *'The invocation of the constructor on type 'View.Companies.Test' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '7'.*

Comment: I also get this warning which might be related: *hides inherited member 'FrameworkElement.NameProperty'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.*

Comment: I assume you're in a `UserControl` which inherits from `FrameworkElement` which already has a `Name` property. I have to go now, but when I'll be near a computer again, I'll try to help.

Comment: I now have this working (just renamed "Name" but I still get no suggestion when I type. One thing I thought I could have wrong is `typeof (WhateverClassYouHave)` bit I simply replaced that with `typeof(CompanyManagement)`, the name of the `Page` this is in. Is that correct? I've added an updated bit of code to my original question.